Is it possible to use a non-Turing-complete language to describe the steps to build a Turing Machine?
First of all, it is impossible to use a Turing-incomplete language to simulate a Turing-complete one (see link)
However, is it possible to use a Turing-incomplete language to describe the steps to build a Turing Machine?
A hypothetical example: A program in our Turing-incomplete "language" consists of a mere sequence of 2D coordinates, specified as pairs of integers. The interpreter for this language merely reads a coordinate pair, and then uses it to identify a cell in a 2D grid. The cells have on/off states, so the interpreter sets a cell's state to "ON" and then moves on to the next "instruction"/coordinate pair. At the end of the input, the grid is used as an initial state for a standard Game of Life simulation which is run in your favourite Turing-complete language, for example C.
Note the following may be important:

Whether "build" has a formal definition in the same way as "simulate" seems to.
The fact that the Game of Life itself is Turing-complete
Whether building a Turing machine in Game of Life is actually "building a Turing machine", ie. whether it's important that it's done from the ground-up, therefore including the building of the Game of Life itself (if so, where is the fundamental "ground"?)

Inspired by the question "Is English Turing-complete".

@Li-yao Xia 's recent blog post Programming Turing machines with regexes might be relevant. In the end it all boils down to the formal definitions you use, so it's hard to answer a question like this one without those.

What do the input and output of programs in this hypothetical language look like?

I'm suggesting an answer to my own question here but I won't mark it as the solution in case someone more knowledgeable comes up with something better.
If "building" a Turing machine merely consists of programming Turing machine A inside the context of Turing Machine B and not actually executing it, then yes, this thought experiment shows it is possible to specify a Turing-complete language using a Turing-incomplete one. Therefore, Turing-completeness or incompleteness is only a statement about the execution of a Turing machine and not its specification.
